# How do I get the Visual Studio Load Test Agent to use the servers second CPU

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, stress-testing

I am running a Visual Studio Load Test using an Agent on one of our servers. This server has two CPU and I have a licence for the Test Agent to use both. 
My question is how do I configure the Test Agent service to use the second cpu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run load tests on multi-core computers, load generation is limited as follows:

If the computer is running Visual Studio Team System Test Edition or Visual Studio Team System, the load generation is limited to one core.

If the computer is running Visual Studio Team System Test Load Agent, the load generation is not limited; it runs on all cores and processors.